# How can i animate an SVG stroke color transition with velocity.js?

Tags: svg, velocity.js

I would like to animate an SVG stroke color change from say, red to green.
Is this possible?
I have managed to do so with the "fill" property, but for some reason i cannot do it with stroke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be something along the lines of:

```
  .velocity({
    strokeRed: 0,
    strokeGreen: 255,
    strokeBlue: 0
    });
```

My understanding is that linear 1s should the default timing, perhaps adding a named easing will enable that,

```
  .velocity({
    strokeRed: 0,
    strokeGreen: 255,
    strokeBlue: 0
    }, "easeInSine");
```

Also, you can simply use "stroke", but note that stroke requires a hex value, unlike those listed above which can either be unitless or a percent.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you answer, it's not transitioning between the colors, it changes instantly.

Comment: @danikoren Just updated the answer to ideally solve your problem